# Meteor method containing insert not returning record ID as result

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am writing attempting to return the id from an insert that's occurring within my Meteor.methods.

Server code:

```
Meteor.methods({
  newCompanyReview: insertCompanyReview,
});

function insertCompanyReview(company,text,rating){
  var cid;
  cid = Companies.insert({
    company: company,
    text: text,
    rating: rating,
  });
  console.log(cid);
  return cid;
}
```

I am assuming that returning the cid variable in the above block returns the variable. However, when I try this in the chrome inspector.

```
> hello = Meteor.call("newCompanyReview",company="Test");
5WFHWoXgvs3tv8QTo
undefined
>hello
undefined
```

This does successfully insert into the DB. Why isn't return returning the id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here, its a `callback`, make this `Meteor.call` asyncrhonus, like this

```
 Meteor.call("newCompanyReview",company="Test",function(err,result){
      if(!err){
       console.log("The new object id is " + result)
       //or put the id in a Session
        Session.set("newObjectId",result)
      }
})
```

With this you can run on the console just a `Session.get("newObjectId")`

Comment: OK, thank you -- I think the asyncSession.get/set is a good fix. But why is the variable "hello" returning unassigned in the above? Per the docs I guess it's a sync call [link](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) but why would that make a difference?

Comment: Thats an expected behavior, you should use the async call and assng the var hello = result sorry bad formatting im on my cellphone

Comment: Gotcha -- this worked: `var hello; Meteor.call("newCompanyReview",company="Test",function(err,result){hello = result;});` I still don't completely understand why the sync call doesn't return, but we've gotten my id working without a session.get so I'll accept the answer. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer is incomplete. See the discussion [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-return-value-on-meteor-call-in-client/1277/3?u=steve). To quote Steve:

A Meteor method is usually composed of 2 parts: a server-side part (let's call it the *server-side method*) and a client-side part (let's call it *the stub*).

If, from the client, you want to get the result of the server-side method, use the callback argument of the [Meteor.call](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) function:

```
Meteor.call('myMethod', arg1, arg2, function(error, result) {
    // 'result' is the method return value
});
```

If, from the client, you want to get the result of the stub, use this undocumented parameter of the [Meteor.apply](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_apply) function:

```
var result = Meteor.apply('myMethod', [arg1, arg2],      { returnStubValue: true });
```

Some may say using `returnStubValue` is misleading. Refer to the first link for more.